# Where can I find interesting .Net screencasts ? (F#, IronRuby, IronPython,...)

Tags: .net

I'm looking for **interesting screencasts targetting .Net** (no podcasts) to extend what I already propose on my screencast aggregator at http://www.learnivore.com.

Can you help me find the most interesting ones you'd be aware of ?

Those I already know:

- http://www.dimecasts.net
- http://www.monotouch.info (.Net development on iPhone!)
- a series of 4 F# screencasts I can't find back
- plus another one I can't disclose yet

I tend to avoid conferences, talks or recordings with poor sound quality - I mostly keep content "à la PeepCode", hands-on material.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I could be wrong here, but this reads more like a plug for your site than a real question.

Comment: hey - sorry if it feels like this, that's not my intention really.

I already have plenty of happy subscribers - my goal here is really to find some interesting screencasts about .Net, because I'd like to broaden the content a bit (it's currently mostly ruby/rails/iphone stuff).

But well - thanks for the comment anyway :) If you find any interesting resources, please comment again!

cheers

-- Thibaut

Answer (score 0):

There is some good stuff at [DNR tv](http://www.dnrtv.com/). It is a weekly show on a variety of .Net topics.